# Include Sharepoint WSP in TFS Build Definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

How to configure the Team Foundation Server 2010 Build Definition to package and include the SharePoint 2010 WSP file with the Build Output of my solution?

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass below MSBuild Commandline Argument in Build Definition:

/p:IsPackaging=True

Please check this MSDN library for detailed information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx